Invalid webhook signature - Api Binance en Laravel
Estoy integrando un webhook de Binance Pay en Laravel. El problema ocurre cuando intento verificar la firma del webhook recibido. El error indica que la verificación de la firma falla porque la firma calculada localmente no coincide con la firma recibida de Binance Pay.
Detalles del error:
Firma calculada localmente: 12D4C0046732A8C0F45A17ADC02B1D355BF31F7596A49B9E8448DC94406E0F9C2B6C3EDF2428832D64FF9A86E793114C4442F0C42E616931C2D92B5FCF54D300
Firma recibida del webhook: 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
Payload del webhook: JSON con datos de transacción (detallados en el error).
El log indica que el resultado de la verificación de la firma es false, y por eso no puedo procesar correctamente los datos del webhook.
Contexto técnico:
Lenguaje y Framework: PHP con Laravel.
Proceso de verificación de la firma:
Uso hash_hmac con el algoritmo sha512 para generar la firma.
Concateno el timestamp, el nonce, y el payload JSON en el orden esperado, separándolos con saltos de línea (\n), luego aplico hash_hmac con la clave secreta de Binance Pay.
[2024-09-24 19:15:57] production.ERROR: Webhook signature verification failed {"calculated":"334CED72775E43575E1E6EB42756D0AF1CC572B2EDEE0175224677935F2F97AD46E89AEB124E60B6CE5B640017B7AA0AA79FB54FD3D698E00AF4A9B09398B868","received":"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","payload":"{"bizType":"PAY","data":"{\"merchantTradeNo\":\"GUBT2528time1727215852\",\"productType\":\"01\",\"productName\":\"GUBT Credits\",\"transactTime\":1727215912549,\"tradeType\":\"WEB\",\"totalFee\":0.01000000,\"currency\":\"USDT\",\"transactionId\":\"P_A1NJTZB3KQW71112\",\"openUserId\":\"a5acad74c090be5ff37213ad246560c9\",\"commission\":0.00010,\"paymentInfo\":{\"payerId\":857244994,\"payMethod\":\"funding\",\"paymentInstructions\":[{\"currency\":\"PEPE\",\"amount\":1215.62,\"price\":0.00000822}],\"channel\":\"DEFAULT\"}}","bizIdStr":"320789071616180224","bizId":320789071616180224,"bizStatus":"PAY_SUCCESS"}"}
[2024-09-24 19:15:57] production.INFO: Signature verification result {"result":false}
[2024-09-24 19:15:57] production.ERROR: Invalid webhook signature
Mi codigo:
<?php
namespace App\Services\Gateways;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class BinancePayService
{
    protected $client;
    protected $apiKey;
    protected $secretKey;
    protected $apiUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiKey = config('binance_pay.api_key');
        $this->secretKey = config('binance_pay.secret_key');
        $this->apiUrl = config('binance_pay.api_url');
        $this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->apiUrl]);
    }

    public function testConnectivity()
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->get('/binancepay/openapi/v2/general/ping');
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
            
            Log::info('Binance Pay API connectivity test', [
                'status_code' => $statusCode,
                'response' => $body
            ]);
            
            return $statusCode === 200;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API connectivity test failed', [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()
            ]);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function createOrder($merchantTradeNo, $totalFee, $successUrl, $cancelUrl, $currency = 'USDT')
    {
        Log::info('Starting createOrder', [
            'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo,
            'totalFee' => $totalFee,
            'currency' => $currency
        ]);

        $timestamp = (string)round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
        $payload = [
            'env' => [
                'terminalType' => 'WEB'
            ],
            'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo,
            'orderAmount' => $totalFee,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'goods' => [
                'goodsType' => '01',
                'goodsCategory' => '7000',
                'referenceGoodsId' => 'GUBT001',
                'goodsName' => 'GUBT Credits',
            ],
            'returnUrl' => $successUrl,
            'cancelUrl' => $cancelUrl,
        ];
        $jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);
        
        Log::debug('Prepared payload', ['payload' => $payload]);

        $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $jsonPayload);
        Log::debug('Generated signature', [
            'signature' => $signature,
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'nonce' => $nonce
        ]);

        try {
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
            ];

            Log::debug('Request headers', ['headers' => $headers]);

            $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order', [
                'headers' => $headers,
                'json' => $payload
            ]);
            
            $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            Log::info('Received response from Binance Pay', [
                'status_code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
                'body' => $responseBody
            ]);

            $result = json_decode($responseBody, true);
            
            if ($result['status'] === 'SUCCESS') {
                Log::info('Binance Pay order created successfully', ['result' => $result]);
                return $result['data'];
            } else {
                Log::error('Binance Pay order creation failed', ['result' => $result]);
                throw new \Exception('Failed to create Binance Pay order: ' . ($result['errorMessage'] ?? 'Unknown error'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
                'payload' => $payload,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function queryOrder($merchantTradeNo)
    {
        Log::info('Starting queryOrder', ['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);

        $timestamp = (string)round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
        $payload = ['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo];
        $jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);

        Log::debug('Prepared payload', ['payload' => $payload]);

        $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $jsonPayload);
        Log::debug('Generated signature', [
            'signature' => $signature,
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'nonce' => $nonce
        ]);

        try {
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
            ];

            Log::debug('Request headers', ['headers' => $headers]);

            $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order/query', [
                'headers' => $headers,
                'json' => $payload
            ]);

            $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            Log::info('Received response from Binance Pay', [
                'status_code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
                'body' => $responseBody
            ]);

            $result = json_decode($responseBody, true);
            
            if ($result['status'] === 'SUCCESS') {
                Log::info('Binance Pay order query successful', ['result' => $result]);
                return $result['data'];
            } else {
                Log::error('Binance Pay order query failed', ['result' => $result]);
                throw new \Exception('Failed to query Binance Pay order: ' . ($result['errorMessage'] ?? 'Unknown error'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
                'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function checkOrderStatus($merchantTradeNo)
    {
        Log::info('Starting checkOrderStatus', ['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);

        $timestamp = (string)round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
        $payload = ['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo];
        $jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);

        Log::debug('Prepared payload', ['payload' => $payload]);

        $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $jsonPayload);
        Log::debug('Generated signature', [
            'signature' => $signature,
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'nonce' => $nonce
        ]);

        try {
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
            ];

            Log::debug('Request headers', ['headers' => $headers]);

            $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order/query', [
                'headers' => $headers,
                'json' => $payload
            ]);

            $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            Log::info('Received response from Binance Pay', [
                'status_code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
                'body' => $responseBody
            ]);

            return json_decode($responseBody, true);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
                'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function verifyWebhookSignature($headers, $payload)
    {
        Log::info('Starting verifyWebhookSignature', ['headers' => $headers, 'payload' => $payload]);

        // Extraer los headers necesarios
        $timestamp = $this->getHeader($headers, 'binancepay-timestamp');
        $nonce = $this->getHeader($headers, 'binancepay-nonce');
        $signature = $this->getHeader($headers, 'binancepay-signature');

        Log::debug('Extracted webhook headers', [
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'nonce' => $nonce,
            'signature' => $signature
        ]);

        if (empty($timestamp) || empty($nonce) || empty($signature)) {
            Log::error('Missing required headers for signature verification', [
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            return false;
        }

        $calculatedSignature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload);
        Log::debug('Calculated signature', ['calculatedSignature' => $calculatedSignature]);

        $result = hash_equals($signature, $calculatedSignature);

        if (!$result) {
            Log::error('Webhook signature verification failed', [
                'calculated' => $calculatedSignature,
                'received' => $signature,
                'payload' => $payload
            ]);
        } else {
            Log::info('Webhook signature verification successful');
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function getHeader($headers, $name)
    {
        $name = strtolower($name);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            if (strtolower($key) === $name) {
                return is_array($value) ? $value[0] : $value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    private function generateNonce()
    {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    }

    private function generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload)
    {
        $payloadToSign = $timestamp . "\n" . $nonce . "\n" . $payload . "\n";
        return strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $payloadToSign, $this->secretKey));
    }
}


pareciera que estas enviando el array ($payload) y no el json ($jsonPayload) usado para calcular el hmac ...'json' => $payload, si hay una conversión implicita en el method post de $this->client puede que ahí esté la discrepancia.
